# How to measure the Hydrogen wavefunction from an inertial frame in motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hamiltonian

I want to calculate how the wave function evolves for a hydrogen atom in its lowest energy state ($n=1$) if its center of mass is moving with a relativistic low-speed $v$.

I expect, of course, that the result will be $$\psi (t,\mathbf{x})=\psi (0,\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}t)*e^{-jE/h_{bar}},$$ where $E$ is the particle’s energy, which should have an additional kinetic energy term $\frac{1}{2}m_{e}v^{2}$ that is the same everywhere since there is no current in the rest state.

This time evolution means that $|\psi |$ will grow in those points that are “in front” of the center of mass (since the center is moving toward it), while it will decrease in the points that are "in the back".

I would expect that this result can be achieved by applying the time evolution operator to the wave so that $\psi (\delta t,\mathbf{x})=\psi (0,\mathbf{x})+\delta \partial_{t} \psi (\delta t,\mathbf{x})$ however,  since the Hamiltonian is real, it seems that it can only cause a change in the wave function’s phase, but not in its absolute value, therefore I conclude that the Hamiltonian is not being equal to $\partial_{t} \psi (\delta t,\mathbf{x})$ outside the particle’s rest frame but that is a quite unexpected result.

What am I doing wrong?